# How do I find where a string in is saved in my virtual memory? Using gdb to Debug .cc file

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I have an executable file that was compiled from a .cc file. I'm now debugging with the gdb. In line 66 of my code I have:

```
cout << "Mean: " << mean << endl;
```

I'm now trying to find where "Mean: " is saved in my virtual memory. Any tips?
I've tried different commands like find and print but have had no breakthroughs.

Does anybody have any tips?

Comment: Just stick a breakpoint on that line and then disassemble the code - the call to `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)` will have that address as a parameter. But this runtime address may change on each execution, depending on where the initialized data segment happens to get mapped. What are you intending to do with the address once you find it?

Comment: List the assembly code of the function.

Comment: You can step into the first invocation of `operator<<` call and you should see the address of "Mean: " in parameters to that call.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure some stuff out :) thanks for the answers,
my output when I set a breakpoint is:
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe888) at sd.cc:66
does this mean, the string is saved in 0x7fffffffe888?

Comment: That's the address of argv.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways you could find the string.

Let's compile this test:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int arch, char *argv[])
{
  double mean = 0.5;
  std::cout << "Mean: " << mean << std::endl;
}
```

1. Use disassembly. Set breakpoint on the `std::cout` line:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main (arch=1, argv=0x7fffffffe328) at t.cc:5
5         std::cout << "Mean: " << mean << std::endl;
(gdb) info line 5
Line 5 of "t.cc" starts at address 0x555555555191 <main(int, char**)+28> and ends at 0x5555555551a4 <main(int, char**)+47>.
(gdb) disas 0x555555555191,0x5555555551a4+1
Dump of assembler code from 0x555555555191 to 0x5555555551a5:
=> 0x0000555555555191 <main(int, char**)+28>:   lea    0xe71(%rip),%rsi        # 0x555555556009
   0x0000555555555198 <main(int, char**)+35>:   lea    0x2ec1(%rip),%rdi        # 0x555555558060 <_ZSt4cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4>
   0x000055555555519f <main(int, char**)+42>:   callq  0x555555555040 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt>
   0x00005555555551a4 <main(int, char**)+47>:   movsd  -0x8(%rbp),%xmm0
End of assembler dump.
```

Above you can see register `rsi` being loaded with value `0x555555556009`, which is passed as second argument to the `std::operator<< ()`. It must contain the string. Indeed:

```
(gdb) x/s 0x555555556009
0x555555556009: "Mean: "
```

2. Use `info file` to find `.rodata` section (in which this string resides) and `find` commands:

```
(gdb) info file
Symbols from "/tmp/a.out".
Native process:
        Using the running image of child process 905.
        While running this, GDB does not access memory from...
Local exec file:
        `/tmp/a.out', file type elf64-x86-64.
        Entry point: 0x555555555090
        0x00005555555542a8 - 0x00005555555542c4 is .interp
...
        0x0000555555556000 - 0x0000555555556018 is .rodata
...

(gdb) find 0x0000555555556000, 0x0000555555556018, {char[6]}"Mean: "
0x555555556009
1 pattern found.
```